# Usage of "would" in future tense

Tags: tenses

Please clarify. This sentence talks about the future event

"Which political party would you vote for in the 2019 assembly elections?"

If we talk about the future that can happen, why would somebody use "would"? can we use "will" in the above sentence in the place of "Would"

Comment: Using *would* suggests *if:* "...if you were given the chance," perhaps; or "would you like to vote for". Just *would* on its own seems unidiomatic.

Comment: In addition to Andrew's 'implied conditionals' (I'd add 'if the situation then were what we face now', which is not too well thought out but usually what people have in mind), the use of 'would' is more hedged, less challenging than 'will'.

Answer (score 2):

*Would* has multiple definitions.

It CAN be the past tense of "will". However, it can also express the conditional mood. This is the case in your sentence.

Putting *will* instead of *would*, while still grammatically correct, changes the meaning. *Would* has a lower modality than *will* because it suggests a condition (that is not present in the sentence). As a result, the question is less confronting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional sentence with the condition being implied. One obvious condition being "if the 2019 election were being held today, which candidate would you vote for."

Strictly speaking, the question "which candidate will you vote for in 2019" should elicit at least some answers along the lines of "It depends on what happens over the next two years."